# Request Factory Stable Id, @ID when use @Parent

Tags: google-app-engine

I am wondering if there is a way to get the stableId of an entity on the server? Or is there a better solution to my situation?

In my app I have two entities A and B. B has a parent A.

```
A Class

      @ID 
      Long id

      String name

B Class

    @Parent A

     @ID 
     Long id

     String value
```

I have a broadcast system that sends messages to registered clients and notifies them when these objects have changed. If I send A and match by ID everything will be fine. If I try to match by ID with B, I will have problem since the id will not be unique.

```
B Message
     Long id
```

When the client receives the B Message above and if I try to compare the id fields it will be the same for multiple B objects.

How is this situation best handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects that have ancestors (like B) have a key that is a combination of its own ID and the ancestor's ID.  Since you haven't shown your code in detail, I can't address it directly, but I can suggest two ways of dealing with this.

1. Use object B's Key instead of its id.  They key includes the reference to A.
2. Since a Key is large, you might not want to use the entire key.  In this case, you need to use both A's id and B's id in order to identify B.  With both ids, you can get B.  You can either reconstruct the Key and get B by key, or use an ancestor query specifying A as the ancestor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am currently using your second suggestion for the same reasons you mentioned. I just wasn't sure if there was a better way....